# How I can change the required capability for an admin menu without editing the plugin file?

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I need to change the capability required for an added admin menu page. By default the plugin added the capability manage_options which I need to change. How can I change this without editing the plugin file?

Comment: Even if there is a hook for that, I'd guess you'd need to change the permission check on the page it links to which I doubt you could do with a hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functioning of the code below depends a lot on how the plugin in question was built.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_capability' );

function change_capability() {

    remove_menu_page(
        $menu_slug,
    );

    add_menu_page(
        $page_title,
        $menu_title,
        $new_capability,
        $menu_slug,
    );

}
```

Comment: Is that the only way, to remove the menu option and re-add it? How does that put the replacement menu option back in the same place?

Comment: [add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) function has a parameter called $position. It determines the page position on menu. So to put it in the same place you need to know the position number in the original declaration.